# Tag all languages in question or just ones deemed relevant?

Tags: discussion, tags

Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58534494/i-have-animated-buttons-in-my-page-but-it-not-show-in-fire-fox-browser?noredirect=1#comment103392324_58534494 (now deleted)

I rolled back an edit which removed the language tags `php` and `codeigniter` because they are present in the code. The earlier editor explains that the PHP part cannot be involved in the problem being described.

Should the question be tagged by all the languages and frameworks that it uses or just the ones that (somebody decides) are relevant? (and who, then, decides?)

Comment: You need to think audiences. "Will this tag bring the right experts to this question". Experts tend to follow strict sets of tags (with wtached and ignored tags settings). Chose quality over quantity.

Comment: @rene that's a good rule. To clarify, the *right* experts is the key. If you have problem with *HTML* yet you tag with PHP because that's what you use to generate the HTML, that's most likely not the correct expertise needed. Unless the problem is that the HTML is generated incorrectly, then you most likely want people who know HTML to answer you. Some of those would also know PHP but, again, you want them from HTML knowledge, not because they know PHP *and* HTML.

Comment: If I was watching the PHP tag looking for questions about PHP I would have removed that tag. The problem in that question has nothing at all do to with PHP. The problem would manifest itself no matter what framework was used to generate the markup. Rolling back that edit was wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @ivarni I agree with you. In fact, I'd go further and say that the PHP present in the code block is not only completely irrelevant, it *harms* the question. This is now neither *minimal* nor *complete* and *verifiable* (nor *representative) example. We can't reproduce the issue without having the PHP code to generate the HTML. All that's needed is the HTML output or even completely fictitious PHP output. Heck, the whole `<?php...>` can probably be removed without harming the validity of the example in terms of reproducing the error.

Comment: "*Should the question be tagged by all the languages and frameworks that it uses or just the ones that (somebody decides) are relevant? (and who, then, decides?)*" more on this point, actually - *why* would you want all languages and frameworks? Nowadays you are not even going to fit all of them in the five tags allowed - OP likely uses a database, so they nee `[mysql]` (or any other DB engine/dialect) which will also imply `[rdbms]`. And they serve that code to the browser, so do they need to add `[apache]`? I also see `window.onscroll` but no [tag:onscroll] tag. I think you get the idea.

Comment: @VLAZ Those are good points, But I think you're making a bit of a straw man out of my position. If there were sql queries, then I would think it should be tagged with sql or mysql. If there were server configuration scripts then I would think it should be tagged with apache. But I still think a code block that involves several languages should be tagged with those languages. (Incidentally, for the question in question, there's no jquery anywhere so I'd sooner remove that one.) If some of the languages aren't pertinent to the problem experienced, that would seem to belong in an answer.

Comment: I disagree that it belongs in an answer. Editing a question is open for all users to improve it. If a tag brings nothing to the question and is *wrong*, then I don't think we need to wait to post an answer to point it out. There are many, *many* questions tagged both `[java]` and `[javascript]` where the asker clearly doesn't know the difference and only talks about one or the other. Removing the irrelevant tag is the same there as is when removing PHP when it's not a PHP issue.

Comment: Tags describe the ***content*** of the question, not its context or milieu. The fact that you also have PHP code somewhere in your project is not relevant unless you're asking a question about that PHP code. Similarly, it doesn't matter what IDE you're using, or what operating system you're running, unless the question is specifically about that environment.

Comment: @CodyGray I have asked a separate question [about this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392457/secret-policing-in-web-development-tags)

Comment: I don't understand what your new question is asking that I didn't already answer in the comment above. Note that this is nothing special/different for web development tags. It is true for *all* tags. You don't stick a "Netbeans" tag on your Java question just because you happen to be using the Netbeans IDE. That tag is only for questions *about* the Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I still think a code block that involves several languages should be tagged with those languages

No. This of course is particular to web development: you have code that runs on the server (PHP, Java, Python, ASP.NET, C++, CGI, ...) which generates HTML markup.

If the question is about the HTML markup, the PHP part (as long as it's entirely under the user's control, so no "serverside control framework" that generates the HTML for you) is entirely irrelevant.

In fact, the OP can recreate it as a jsFiddle, a snippet, or give it a name, purely existing of HTML and CSS, and still reproduce the issue. Hence the PHP tag being irrelevant.

Now that the OP is unable to create a proper MRE, that's their problem. That doesn't mean we should leave those tags on the question.

Answer (score 2):

> Should the question be tagged by all the languages and frameworks that it uses or just the ones that (somebody decides) are relevant?

Just the ones that (somebody decides) are relevant.

> (and who, then, decides?)

The users who Stack Overflow deems trustworthy to edit the question. Which is to say, anyone, where those edits are subject to review, or those over 2000 rep, which are not subject to review.