# Secret policing in web development tags

Tags: discussion, tags

After many years programming as an amateur in a few niche languages, I started getting into web development. I started checking the JavaScript tag to learn and help out. But very quickly encountered a situation that made me run away screaming.

I was browsing the JavaScript tag and found a question that was tagged JavaScript and jQuery and since I'm familiar with both, I pulled it up and started to read. Hidden in the code (you had to scroll to the right to see it) there was some PHP code. Checking the comments and the edit history, it appeared that someone had edited and removed the PHP tag because it wasn't "relevant to the issue at hand".

I rolled back the edit to restore the OP's original tags, because whether or not that aspect of the code was causing the problem, it was literally there in the code. Someone ignorant of PHP would be unable to see past that and offer help or even understand what it was doing. As a longtime user of the site with sufficient reputation my rollback edit did not require any approval.

I left a comment explaining what I had done and why. The other editor reasserted the same claim previously made. And in order to avoid a comment war/rollback war, I [took it to meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390740/tag-all-languages-in-question-or-just-ones-deemed-relevant).

The comments and answers all appeared to cite a secret rule that goes on in the Web Development tags. My question was downvoted and closed as a duplicate of another question. The proposed duplicate does not in fact address what I was asking and the answers there appear (to me) to contradict the gang's position. The proposed duplicate says that using more tags is preferred, because the question may attract more views and thereby be more likely receive help.

The OP of the instigating question deleted their post, and I can only assume it was because of the brawl that ensued.

Throughout the interaction, I tried to patiently explain my reasoning and to understand the positions of the others involved and carefully point out where I thought their reasoning was misapplied or inconsistent with the FAQ and site rules. But the whole thing became very frustrating because it felt like everyone else was working backwards from a foregone conclusion.

I have spent a few months now avoiding Stack Overflow entirely so I could cool down.

**Is this how the Web Development tags ought to be managed? Was I wrong to ask for clarity on meta?**

Note: this question is not a feature request, and per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) if you disagree with the position I have expressed that belongs in an (upvote to an) answer and not a downvote to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366395/adding-tags-to-a-question-that-are-relevant-to-the-answer-proposed

Comment: Downvotes aren't mean, just so we're clear...

Comment: Just keep in mind that [php], [jquery] and [codeigniter] are yesteryear's fad.  SO users are apt to easily find one more nail to drive in.  https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=jquery%2Cphp

Answer (score 19):

It was fine to seek clarity and guidance from Meta, but the likely circumstance is that you're dissatisfied with the answer you received.

The guiding advice is that you should only add tags that are relevant to the question being posed.  If the question is *more* about the HTML and CSS and JavaScript in the question, then the fact that PHP code also exists in the question is immaterial, and expert answerers can safely ignore that part of the code in an answer that would satisfy, especially since the PHP code in the question you linked is only needed to generate an anchor tag's href.

The only way this policing would've been considered "secret" is if you had went to Meta and not received *any* answer as to how this should be handled.

Answer (score 3):

How about a different example.

Say someone has a question about [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/). Their layout is wrong at the small device size. They create a snippet demonstrating their issue and it includes both Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript files. There is no JavaScript code in their snippet or additional CSS.

It would be inappropriate to tag the question with JavaScript. It's not relevant to the problem and most likely shouldn't be used to fix it.

Likewise, it would not appropriate to tag it with Sass just because Bootstrap uses it. The OP didn't include any new CSS or Sass so that isn't the problem and it isn't helpful to bring Sass experts to that question.